# socket.broadcast.emit not sending to clients

Tags: node.js, socket.io

I'm trying to make a simple chat app, so far everything works correctly until I've gotten to the part where I have to send the message to every connected user except the user who sent the message, I've tried to follow tutorials, refer to documentation but nothing has worked, so I have no clue, I'm new to Node and JS in general. code :

```
//server side 
const io = require("socket.io")(3000)


io.on("connection", socket => {
    console.log("New User ")
    socket.on("chat-message", message => {
        if (message !== "") {
            socket.broadcast.emit("broadcast-message", message)
        } else {
            console.log("Empty String")
        }

    })
})
```

```
//client side
const socket = io("http://localhost:3000")
const messageForm = document.getElementById("send-container")
const messageInput = document.getElementById("message-input")

messageForm.addEventListener("submit", event => {
    event.preventDefault()
    const message = messageInput.value
    socket.emit("chat-message", message)
    messageInput.value = ""

})
socket.on("broadcast-message", message => {
    console.log("broadcast : " + message)
})
```

Answer (score 0):

I think something wrong with setting up the server, Try this.

```
//server-side
const express=require("express")
const app=express()
const server=require("http").createServer(app)
 //pass server variable instead of port
const io=require("socket.io")(server)
server.listen(3000,()=>console.log(`Listening to port 3000`))
```

In client-side only `socket=io()` is required. If you pass localhost URL, this will throw an error after deployment